# Proof of properties of Fourier series in CT

Tags: continuous-signals, fourier-series, proof

I feel problem in understanding the proof of Fourier series properties

1. **Time scaling**
   \begin{align}
   b_k &= \frac{1}{T}\int_{T}x(t)e^{jk\omega_0t}dt\\
   & = \frac{a}{T}\int_{T/a}x(at)e^{jk(\omega_0a)t}dt\tag{$\scriptstyle{a - \text{scaling factor}}$}\\
   & = \frac{a}{T}\int_{T}x(L)e^{jk\omega_0L}\frac{dL}{a}\tag{$\scriptstyle{L=at}$}\\
   &= \frac{1}{T}\int_{T}x(L)e^{jk\omega_0L}dL = a_k\\
   \end{align}
   For this I want to ask that how $T/a$ term in the integral changes to $T$, and $dt$ changes to $dL/a$?
2. **Multiplication**
   \begin{align}
   x(t)y(t)&= \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} a_k  e^{jk\omega_0t}\sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} b_k  e^{jl\omega_0t}\\ &=\sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} \sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty} a_k b_le^{j(k+l)\omega_0t}\\
   &=\sum^{+\infty}_{m\ =\ -\infty} \left[\sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty} a_{m-l} b_l\right]e^{jm\omega_0t}\tag{$\scriptstyle{m=k+l}$}
   \end{align}
   I couldn't understand this last step, why the summation changes from $k$ to only  $m$? Shouldn't it be $m-l$ and also is it done here to prove the multiplication property? or there are more steps?

Comment: please write in comment the reason before giving down

Comment: There is a mistake in your last expression in time scaling. The integrating variable is dL and not dt. In your multiplication steps all the steps are correct. He is taking the substitution m=k+l. so now k becomes (m-l).But the limits of integration of k are expressed in terms of m. m=K+l. now if k=-infinity, m=-infinity and if k=+infinity,m=+infinity. All this is being done to express fourier coefficients of product of x(t)y(t) as discrete convolution of individual fourier series coefficients ak and bk.

Comment: see when you are making a substitution of L=at in integral, here you are doing definite integrals , so you have to change the limits of integration  also. So if L=at ,then you have to  change everything  with respect to L. so  now the integration limits are t=0 and t=T/a before making substitution L=at. After L=at substitution, you have to change limits with respect to L. So when t=0 L=a.0=0 and when t=T/a, L=a.(T/a)=T.That's how limits are changing to T. with regard to dt/a, it is because L=at.differentiate b.s. you will get dL=dt.a. so dt=dL/a. change that dt/a to dL/a. That's a mistake.

Comment: yes i have change it to dL, can you please help me to understand how $T/a$ term changes to$T$ in the integral changes and $dt$ to $dL/a$

Comment: @Talasila: i understand the first part completely.. for 2 questions. i still have confusion why the summation is not from $m-l$ why it is from $m$. second thing, the multiplication property ends here? in the book only mentioned the term in brackets

Comment: First try to understand why he is making the substitution of m=k+l,he is trying to express whatever is in k with respect to m. so you have to change limits of integration also from k to m, so now when k is -infinity, the equivalent value of m is -infinity. This is because once k is -infinity,no matter whatever the value of l be, m is always equal to -infinity. similarly observe for k=+infinity. Observe the last expression of your multiplication property. it shows clearly the equation in sum of complex exponentials form which will give you fourier series coefficients.

Comment: I understand this but in the book, signals and systems the just mentioned the term in brackets and ignore the summation and exponential term.. i want to know they did

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA There shouldn't be those $dt$'s in your second question. Can you double-check the $x(t)y(t)$ equation ?

Comment: @Gilles, Yes you are right there is no $dt$, i edited that part

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA As I mentioned in one of my previous comments, if you see the general form of exponential series it is of the form of a summation  of fourier series  coefficients with complex exponentials which are harmonic. So in your multiplication case, he is showing you by putting the term in brackets that the resultant of multiplication of two periodic signals  gives a periodic signal whose fourier series coefficient is the discrete convolution of the fourier coefficients of x(t) and y(t). Hence they  have ignored the summation and exponential term after this step.

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA You have still not edited completely. look at your first step in multiplication.There are two dt's there which are meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

- Looking at the change of terms in the equality:
  $$\frac{a}{T}\int_{T/a}x(at)e^{jk(\omega_0a)t}dt = \frac{a}{T}\int_{T}x(L)e^{jk\omega_0L}\frac{dL}{a}$$
  $$at = L\implies \begin{cases}\text{if }t=T/a\implies L=T\\adt=dL\implies dt=\frac{dL}{a}\end{cases}$$
- Looking at the equality again:
  $$ \sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ -\infty} \sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty} a_k b_le^{j(k+l)\omega_0t}=\sum^{+\infty}_{m\ =\ -\infty} \left[\sum^{+\infty}_{l\ =\ -\infty} a_{m-l} b_l\right]e^{jm\omega_0t} $$
  $$m=k+l\implies \begin{cases}k=m-l\quad({\scriptstyle{\rm indeed}})\\\text{and } m-l=\pm \infty \implies  m=\pm\infty+l=\pm\infty\end{cases}$$